# cv filestorage read yaml without the "%YAML:1.0" line specified

Tags: opencv, yaml

I need to write a c++ parser that can read YAML files that look like this:

```
image_width: 1920
image_height: 1200
camera_name: narrow_stereo
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1063.422080, 0.000000, 918.069798, 0.000000, 1063.715929, 590.178737, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]
```

This is my first attempt:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
static cv::Mat CameraMat;
static int ImageWidth, ImageHeight;
cv::FileStorage fs(calibration_file, cv::FileStorage::READ | cv::FileStorage::FORMAT_YAML);
fs["camera_matrix"] >> CameraMat;
fs["image_width"] >> ImageWidth;
fs["image_height"] >> ImageHeight;
```

This fails for a few reasons, relating to the YAML in this config file, not matching the YAML standard opencv expects. If I make three additions to my YAML file, as below, the above code works as expected.

```
%YAML:1.0
image_width: 1920
image_height: 1200
camera_name: narrow_stereo
camera_matrix: !!opencv-matrix
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  dt: d
  data: [1063.422080, 0.000000, 918.069798, 0.000000, 1063.715929, 590.178737, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]
```

My Question is: How can I read these YAML files (without having to edit them)? Can it be done with some cv::FileStorage hack or do I need to write my own parser and constructor from scratch?

Note that without the top line filestorage can't even get past the constructor.

Comment: YAML 1.0 is ancient. You could switch to [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) which implements YAML 1.2, however you will need to implement loading the data to `cv::Mat` yourself.

Comment: it works if I write "YAML 1.2" as well, the point is it just needs some kind of declaration there, which my YAML files don't have.

Comment: In any case, neither YAML version requires the `%YAML` directive, so what OpenCV provides is not standard compliant, which alone should be a good reason to use a different YAML implementation. To dig further into this problem, you should supply information about *how* your current code fails.

Comment: I've found a solution to my problem. Since I am using ROS, ROS has a facility to parse and broadcast YAML on it's own internal parameter server which I then query and manually form the cv::Mat.  but this isn't really a generic answer to this question. so I might just delete this question?

Comment: If the problem is reproducible with the code you posted, you should not delete it since someone might know the real solution and someone else might find this question when encountering the same problem.